# Action 'index' could not be found for <x>Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4.1

So I have just created my rails 4.1.2 project with a controller, `login_controller.rb` and view `login.html.erb`. I have edited my `routes.rb` and removed the already put in route by rails after creating a controller and added another default `match` route which is `:controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => :get`

When I run my server using `rails s` and open `localhost:3000/login` it gives me this error:

```
The action 'index' could not be found for LoginController
```

I do not know why is it looking for an action named 'index'. If I am right then the default action taken by rails without actually specifying one is 'index' so I tried to change my URL and requested this:

```
localhost:3000/login/login
```

Which gave me this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/login/login"
```

How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Here's what my `rake routes` outputs:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
       GET  /:controller(/:action:(/:id))(.:format) :controller#:action
```

Comment: in the directoy of your rails app execute `rake rutes` to see all availables routes and add to your post

Comment: never I use like this routes... sorry. Also check the controller name maybe is `logins_controller.rb` (in plural)

Comment: and do you have a `login` action in your login controller?

Comment: @inye yes i have it.

Comment: and the plural controller (`logins_controller.rb`)?

Comment: @inye no, it's singular.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79222/discussion-between-mohammad-areeb-siddiqui-and-inye).

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a model `User` and controller `UsersController`. In your `routes.rb` file, you list resources and routes to *match* based on controller actions. By default, that resource includes `:index, :show, :new, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy`. You can specify which you want (or not) by doing:

```
# config/routes.rb

# blacklisting - these are not in your controller
resource :users, exclude: [:show, :destroy], via: [:get, :post]

# whitelisting - these are in your controller
resource :users, only: [:index], via: [:get, :post]
```

To my understanding, the filename of your view (unless rendered or an asset) corresponds to the controller action. Is the view for your login page named `index.html.(erb|haml)?`If so, you should define the index even as simply as `def index; end`. However, I suggest you include something that redirects the user to home or the login page, depending whether they are already logged in.

From there, the real magic happens in your controller as you define a method `login`. Here, check the incoming parameters and log the user in if correct. Think of this similar to an `#update` action.

Similar to how you define which actions to include in the routes, you can make your own custom ones. Do note: the [order of routes matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984861/correct-order-of-resources-in-rails-routes-rb). I am not 100% on that concept myself, but this is what I would suggest in your case:

```
#config/routes.rb

resource :login, only: [:index], via: [:get, :post]
match '/login/login' => 'login#login', via: [:get, :post]
```

You can also use `match` to link `/login/index` to the `#login` method. The view would be called `index` still. And just because there is a route for it, you do not need a view for the login action -- it simply parses the parameters, while the index would show error messages.

Comment: so that the first statement in your last code snippet does is that first it checks if the controller is '/login' than it should redirect to 'index' and if that does not match then it should go to login. I do not understand one thing. If the first route does not match then won't it throw a routing error before attempting to do the next route? Also, can you please explain what those 2 statements really do. I know about the second one but can you please elaborate on the first one? P.S I solved my problem by deleting and recreating the controller and including jquery in my application.js. If......

Comment: .....your solution is better than what I did there then please explain it to me or else just tell me that I did the right thing anyways. Thanks. :)

Comment: In my last code snippet, the `resource` line names the controller and defines that you ONLY want the index (of the default index, new, edit, etc) via get/post responses. NO, it will not pick "the next route if the first is missing/wrong". Think of it as this, the index is created first and has higher priority than login.

Comment: If you want to know more about Rails routing, please visit [this guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). I am still novice and am unable to explain it further without going in circles.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui how is the progress of the question? Did everything work?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the desired result. localhost:3000/login/login. Rember to restart server at the end.

app/controller/login_contrtoller.rb

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  def login
  end
end
```

routes

```
get 'login/login'
```

/app/views/login/login.html.erb

```html
<h1>Login#login</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/login/login.html.erb</p>
```

Comment: i did not quite understand what you are talking about.

Comment: The controller file login_controller should be in the /app/controller/login folder and the login.HTML.erb file in app/views/login the login controller. If you run rake routes command in the terminal it will show all the routes that rails thinks is set up. It may not be pointing to login/login as you think.  Try making sure the view is in the app/view golder first before moving the controller the controller does have a "def index end" function in it?

Comment: Moving controller to a new folder gave me an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79222/discussion-between-mohammad-areeb-siddiqui-and-inye).

Comment: Try this in routes instead.   get 'login/login', :controller => 'login'

Answer (score 0):

Add an index action on your LoginController

```
def index
end
```

Comment: But why? I do not need an index action.

Comment: then route to the action you want ```get '/login', to: 'login#login'```

Comment: Also you might want to read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html to understand how routing works.

Comment: The default routing hits the path given i.e. google.com/login looks in the login controller for an index action. If you want to route to login instead you need to specify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79222/discussion-between-mohammad-areeb-siddiqui-and-inye).